# Generating the same 2 random colors for 2 different objects

Tags: html, css, random, colors, p5.js

Basically, I have to generate the same color, chosen randomly, for 2 different bodies. Does anyone have any tip on how I could link the two objects to have the same random colour? Evertime a condition happens, the colour should refresh and both bodies should have that particular colour.
Thx a lot!
//btw any code language is useful

Comment: what did you call 2 different bodies ? one in China and the other one in Nederland ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is to generate the random color once and then set the color of both bodies to that color. Put that in a `refreshColors` function and call that function when your condition is met.

```js
if (condition) {
  refreshColors()
}

function refreshColors () {
  // generate color
  let color = generateRandomColor()

  // set Body A color
  body_a.style.color = color

  // set Body B color
  body_b.style.color = color
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using a [custom property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (also known as *CSS variables*):

```js
function randomColor() {
  const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  
  return `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
}

const root = document.documentElement;

root.style.setProperty("--random-color", randomColor());
```

```css
.element-1,
.element-2 {
  background-color: var(--random-color);
}
```

```html
<p class="element-1">Element 1</p>
<hr />
<p class="element-2">Element 2</p>
```

If you want you can set the custom property to some default value in your CSS file:

```css
:root {
  --random-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

And make sure your elements use this property, using the [CSS `var()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()):

```css
.element-1,
.element-2 {
  background-color: var(--random-color);
}
```

Then you overwrite that property in you if statement using [`style.setProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty):

```js
if (condition) {
  const root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty("--random-color", randomColor());
}
```

Read more about dynamically setting custom properties [in this article](https://vanseodesign.com/css/custom-properties-and-javascript/).